# Copy Data from one Excel Workbook to Another Workbook in Last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am Trying to run this Code, which will copy the Source sheet Row to Destination Sheet last Row, but my this code giving error 400 while compiling,

Advance Thanks for Help

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim sBook_t As String
    Dim sBook_s As String

    Dim sSheet_t As String
    Dim sSheet_s As String

    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    sBook_t = "C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\Free\Calculators.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (sBook_t)
    sBook_s = "C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\Free\PRODUCT_35.xlsm"
    Workbooks.Open (sBook_s)

    sSheet_t = "cstdatalist"
    sSheet_s = "cstdata"

    Sheets(sSheet_s).Range("A2").Copy Destination:=Sheets(sSheet_t).Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Comment: You can find the last row and then copy the data there. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920) the code to find last row.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on following sub.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht, shtLocal As Worksheet
Dim rngPaste As Range
Dim rngLastData, wbPath As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    wbPath = "D:\dBook.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set shtLocal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngPaste = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Destination range set after last used cell of column A

    rngLastData = shtLocal.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Address
    shtLocal.Range("A1:" & rngLastData).Copy rngPaste

    wb.Save
    wb.Close
    Set sht = Nothing
    Set shtLocal = Nothing
    Set rngPaste = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hay this Code is not working for Me on MS Excel, i have done this on Google Sheet but stuck in Microsoft Excel, Below is my Google Sheet Code 
 
' function CopyData(){

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10Grh3DBL4sU');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var SRange = ss.getRange("A3:EO3");
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17gXnrJUV5_qw');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('CalDatabase');
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,SData.length,SData[0].length).setValues(SData);
  
}'
@harun24hr

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Here is my adjustment of your code. What I did is declared the workbooks and the worksheets separately. This way it is clear which workbook/sheet is the source and which is the destination.

```
  Sub CopyData()
        Dim sBook_t As String
        Dim sBook_s As String
        Dim workbook_t As Workbook
        Dim sSheet_t As Worksheet
        Dim sSheet_s As Worksheet


    Dim sSheet_t As String
    Dim sSheet_s As String

    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    sBook_t = "C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\Free\Calculators.xlsx"
      set workbook_t =  Workbooks.Open (sBook_t)
    sBook_s = "C:\Users\Unknown\Desktop\Free\PRODUCT_35.xlsm"
      set workbook_s =  Workbooks.Open (sBook_s)

   set sSheet_t = workbook_t.Sheets("cstdatalist")
   set sSheet_s = workbook_s.Sheets("cstdata")

    sSheet_s.Range("A2").Copy Destination:=sSheet_t.Range("A2")


    End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the Help but this code not working still Label not defined error

Comment: This is the line that is causing you the issue, `On Error GoTo Errorcatch`. Do you have an error handling label defined?  In not try removing this line.